# How to configure an httpclient using Autofac and Polly in old 4.6.1 .Net framework

Tags: c#, autofac, dotnet-httpclient, .net-4.6, polly

There is a legacy app that uses an `httpClient` to interact with Web API backend.

I would like to configure several httpClients in `Autofac` DI container. The configuration must include timeouts, `Polly` (https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) retry policies and probably delegating handlers. These preconfigured httpClients would be injected into another services constructors. I would like to have strong-typed clients that would encapsulate all logic. Named strong-typed should be able to accept parameters (probably via constructor), to set specific properties from application settings.

I'm a little bit confused because most of the provided examples and articles describe the configuration for .Net Core framework. At the same time, I haven't managed to find a 4.6.1 Autofac + Polly example that would cover my case and requirements.

It seems I need to add something like that:

```cs
//Configuration in Autofac DI container
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<IHttpClientFactory>()
        // Not clear how to apply Polly policies in DI container
        // How to pass appsettings values to StrongTypedHttpClient constructor?
        // How to pass delegating handlers? 
        .CreateClient())
        .As<StrongTypedHttpClient>();

public class StrongTypedHttpClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public StrongTypedHttpClient(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        //It is not clear how to apply Polly policies to HttpClient instance
        //How to get an application settings?
    }
    // Http client logic and methods
}

//A consumer class that uses preconfigured strong-typed http client 
public class Consumer
{
    private readonly StrongTypedHttpClient _httpClient;

    public StrongTypedHttpClient(StrongTypedHttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how it could be implemented?

**UPDATE**: As @PeterCsala suggested I have tried HttpClientBuilder interface from Microsoft.Extensions.Http and it worked for me.

Strong-typed http client configuration in Autofac DI container:

```cs
var settings = GetRefreshTokenSettings();
builder.RegisterInstance(settings).AsSelf();

var retryPolicy = HttpPolicyExtensions
                  .HandleTransientHttpError()
                  .Or<TimeoutRejectedException>()
                  .WaitAndRetryAsync(Backoff.LinearBackoff(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300), retryCount: settings.TokenHttpClientRetryCount));
var timeoutPolicy = Policy.TimeoutAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(settings.TokenHttpClientTimeoutInSeconds);

builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<IHttpClientBuilder>()
                       .AddTypedClient<StrongTypedHttpClient>()
                       .AddPolicyHandler(retryPolicy)
                       .AddPolicyHandler(timeoutPolicy));
```

Comment: The AddPolicyHandler extension method is defined against the IHttpClientBuilder interface, which resides inside the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection namespace.

Comment: @PeterCsala It seems IHttpClientBuilder doesn't exist in 4.6.1 version. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.ihttpclientbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.6.1

Comment: Have you tried to add Microsoft.Extensions.Http nuget package to your project. It targets .NET Standard 2.0 so it is compatible with .NET fw 4.6.x as well.